# Powering LEDs through microcontroller pins and transistors

Tags: transistors, stm32, 7segmentdisplay

I'm working on my first ever PCB, and would like to include two 7-segment displays. The device will be powered from mains, so power consumption is not an issue. I have chosen the Broadcom HDSM-293L, with a forward voltage of 2.1V and a maximum current of 25 mA per segment.

The microcontroller I'm using is an STM32F030K6T6, which should be able to deliver 25 mA per pin.

To be able to show seperate digits on the displays I need to be able to toggle the common cathode outputs, but the uC can't sink the current of several LEDs into a single pin, so I'm using transistors for this purpose - a subject I'm not entirely comfortable with. Online tutorials have told me that BJP NPN's are suitable for the purpose, so I've chosen the ON Semiconductor MBT3904DW1T1G, a package of two such transistors suited for 200mA.

The below schematic shows how I've wired GPIOs from the microcontroller through 56Ohm resistors to each anode, and connected the cathodes to the collector of the transistors. I've also connected GPIOs through 1K resistors to the transistor gates.

[image: schematic]

Is this a sensible way of powering the 7-Segment displays? Are the components I've chosen suited for the task? And is everything correctly connected safe in terms of amount of current?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Several people in the comments pointed out that the maximum sourcable current across all the IO pins of the STM is 80 mA. To address this, I'd like to change out the LED resistors for 120 ohm ones, which should reduce the current draw for each segment to 10 mA for a maximum of 70 mA at a time (I don't need the dots).

Comment: I'm using transistors for this purpose - a subject I'm not entirely comfortable with -> Look into high/low side drivers :) Also take a look at the datasheet at page 44 - note ΣIIO(PIN) and the footnote (2)

Comment: Yes, 25mA on one pin. But with strict conditions. Please read the datasheet rating accurately. Also, I like to refer to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/463246/148363) I placed earlier today.

Comment: Design concept is correct for multiplexing the display.  However, the NPN selected is a poor choice. To sink up to 200mA, that part will need a very high base current.  Select a Low Rds, Logic Level gate, N-channel MOSFET instead.  I would use a part like AOD508  (or AOD514 if you don't need huge quantities) http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOD508.pdf or one with similar characterics as this is a bit overkill for 200mA.

Comment: this wasn't asked,  but did you know there are digital ICs that will manage driving a 7-segment display directly for you, with I2C or SPI interfaces, or BCD  to 7 segment decoders.

Comment: @Sorenp I am using the high side to control segments and the low side to control the digit, is there anything wrong with that? The total power consumption is problematic, though, yeah... I'll make an edit to address that

Comment: @CrossRoads thanks! This is just a hobby project, no huge quantities needed, but I'll try to find a transistor with those characteristics

Comment: @vicatcu I am aware of those, but I was hoping to avoid them simply because this is my first PCB project and I'd rather use as few unfamiliar components as possible to reduce the chance of doing something wrong

Comment: An underrated NPN will only lead to a dim display as the processor cannot supply enough base current to achieve full current sink capability.

Comment: @CrossRoads what do you mean by underrated? The current the transistor is rated for?

Comment: Yes - the NPN needs more base current to support 200mA Ic.  N-channel MOSFET needs very little current, in the uA range, to turn on fully and support the current for the 8 LEDs of the display.

Comment: @rdtsc, it is a 2 display unit with common anodes. Two seven segment digits with a decimal point each, so multiplexing between the digits is required.

Comment: @CrossRoads alright I see, so it's underrated because it's BJP, and a MOSFET would be a better choice. Thanks :)

Comment: I just like to mention the "famous" ULN2803A darlington transistor array for this kind of application (But you would need a common anode display with that one)

Comment: @StefanWyss so then I would use the ULN2803A to control individual segments and another pair of transistors to select digit? Changing to a common anode display is not in itself a problem

Comment: @Vegard Yes, you would pull the segments to GND with the ULN2803A and you would need two transistors to multiplex the common anodes of the digits.

Comment: If you use a FET, make sure that it is rated for a gate voltage of 3.3V (or whatever your VDD supply is).  If you use a 2N3904, you want to use about 1/10th as much base current as collector current (this was @CrossRoads's point).  There are "super-beta" BJTs out there that will go into saturation with a base current that's 1/100th or less than the collector current, or you could use an NPN Darlington array.

Comment: I do not like stressing my microprocessor pins to the degree you'd need to here.  Personally, I'd use PNP or P-channel transistors at each segment pin.  You can get pre-biased PNPs that do the job, or use a P-channel FET (and make sure that it's rated for a \$\mathrm{V_{GS}}\$ equal to your VDD).  You'll use a lot less pin current, your processor will be happier, and your board won't be all that much bigger.